# Button_to remove auth token

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, mailto

I use this code to allow the user to send a mail to another user:

```
<%= button_to("Contact me","mailto:#{@formation.usr.email}?subject=#{@formation.name}", class: "fiche__detail__contact") %>
```

Which gives me the following html:

```
<form action="mailto:user@gmail.com?subject=SomeName" class="button_to" method="post">
    <div>
        <input class="fiche__detail__contact" type="submit" value="Me contacter" />
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="cO0XDBcG4j0IfmDJV56sdYSfoLeV9NmhTd+bJu/ku+U=" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And this king of email:

[image]

I tried to set the body of the mail using `&body` but it doesn't work. Also, set `:authenticity_token => false` is not working either.

How can I remove the token?

Comment: Why don't you use the `mail_to` helper ?

Comment: @MaximeMangel nice feature, I didn't knew about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [mail_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to):

```
<%= mail_to @formation.usr.email, "Contact me", :subject => @formation.name, class: "fiche__detail__contact" %>
```